What is the exact nuance of "無心"

絵を描くことは楽しいですか？」


とくに感慨はありません。　無心になりたくてやってるんです」


仏教徒は悟りのために曼荼羅を描き、　あなたは無心を紛らすためにお絵描きなさる

In this back and fort, in the first line, the character wonders is sketching is fun.
The character then replies there is no strong feeling toward it.  he just wants to clear his mind so he does it.
Then in the third line:
"仏教徒は悟りのために曼荼羅を描き、　あなたは無心を紛らすためにお絵描きなさ"
leaving aside the first part of the sentence, I can't make sense of 無心 meaning here?
First he says he wants to be   無心になりたくて then the other character comments he wants to 紛らす it? What is the actual nuance of the word?

無心を紛らす is usually understood to mean "to distract oneself from having an empty mind," i.e., "to try to occupy oneself and avoid idleness".
This indeed seems to be the opposite of what the second person is trying to achieve. It might be a surreal gag where the third person says something convoluted but fails to communicate properly. Please judge based on the context.
